# woocommerce plugin send request to server on add to cart, not on checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I wrote a plugin for woocommerce. It is for a delivery company.

**How does the plugin work?** if a restaurant installs our plugin, the customers of the restaurant will see our company and our price (as a delivery company) in the checkout delivery list. if the customer chooses our company, we will place an order and deliver it to the customer.

**What is the problem?** my problem is: every time a customer adds an item to the cart, woocommerce will send a request to our server to validate the address and calculate shipping price... but why should it send a request to our server for adding an item to the cart? we need to get a request only on checkout... not before that.

On that stage, even we don't have customer's address yet.

plugin uses `woocommerce_shipping_init` api [docs](https://woocommerce.com/document/shipping-method-api/#).

is there any alternative? what is the best practice?

**Where is the problem?**
this is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', $this, 'shipping_init' );
```

and in the `shipping_init` method, I call my server endpoint api to calculate the shipping price.

when I comment this line, the plugin doesn't send any requests. not on `add to cart`, not on `check-out`.(so plugin doesn't work any more).

when I uncomment this line, the plugin will send a request when the customer press `add to cart`. but I expect it sends a request to calculate the price by customer's address when the customer press `check-out` button or visit `/cart` page.

What should I do? is this possible to fix that or not?

Comment: Why not simply add condition if(is_checkout()) add_action ?

Comment: To answer your question why its triggered i think its probably bcs WC()->cart holds data about shipping . For example WC()->cart->get_shipping_total() should return value or not depending on if customer have presaved address.

Comment: @MartinMirchev thank you Martin for your comment. `is_checkout()` is just for `check out page`. it won't work for `https://wordpressexample.com/cart/` page (the page where you put your postal code and it will show you the approximate price).
I think it's how the woocommerce works...there is no solution.
if you think there is no solution put the answer I will ckeck it as the solution

Comment: maybe try with js event updated_shipping_method to send request to your server ? And also at checkout update_checkout event ? Check the events here - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342148/list-of-js-events-in-the-woocommerce-frontend

Comment: @MartinMirchev because we are a delivery company, our clients(restaurants) have their own front-end and theme, do you think I can manage it with front-end? or not?

Comment: Well in that case they will control cart settings too if they want to have calculator or not. In your plugin you have to check depending on woo options how to work. The important is that your plugin must load after woocommerce to be able to listen woo events and its possible sure :)

Comment: @MartinMirchev if you want, just copy and past these comments in a post and I will mark it as the best answer. thank you for your comments